# Autocompletion filenames with prefix in variable

Tags: autocompletion

In Vim I make auto-completion of the filesystem paths just by the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, in insert mode.

In a *Makefile* I sometimes put a path's prefix in a variable. For instance `STYLEDIR=/home/user/style`.

Then I have to refer to a file in that directory on another point in the *Makefile*. For instance

```
pandoc --style $(STYLEDIR)/main.css ...
```

In this case I can't autocomplete with Vim, because Vim is not aware of the value of the `STYLEDIR` variable. I start with `$(STYLEDIR)/` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> and doesn't show the completion.

Is there a way to have autocompletion of files in this case? Maybe a GNU Make plugin for Vim?

Answer (score 3):

**Get variable value**

```
make -p -f/dev/null 2>/dev/null | grep -Po 'var\s*=\s*\K.+'
```

**Complete in vim**

I use [:h complete()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#complete%28%29) in this case, you need to tell it where complete starts and give it a list of candidates.

Assume your current line looks like this:

```
........$(var)/mid0/mid1/mid2/base
                                  ^---cursor position in insert mode
```

The idea is to get `var`, `mid=/mid0/mid1/mid2/` and `base`, send `var` to [:h system()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) to expand it, combine the expanded value with mid and base, send it to [:h glob()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#glob%28%29) , remove leading `expanded var + mid` from every item in glob result, and that's our final complete candidates:

```
inoremap <c-b> <c-r>=<sid>complete_make_var_path()<cr>

function! s:complete_make_var_path()

  " search $(..) backward, do nothing if not found
  let dolllar_pos = searchpos('\v\$\([^)]+\)', 'bn', line('.'))
  if dolllar_pos == [0, 0]
    return ''
  endif

  " get prefix from $ to current column -1
  let dir_base = getline('.')[ dolllar_pos[1] - 1 : col('.') - 2 ]

  " separate $(var)/mid0/mid1/mid2/base into var, mid, base
  let [var, mid, base] = matchlist(dir_base, '\v\$\(([^)]+)\)(.*/)?(.*)')[1:3]

  " expand var, erase trailing newline
  let evar = system('make -p -f/dev/null 2>/dev/null | grep -Po ''' . var . '\s*=\s*\K.+''' )
  if empty(evar)
    return ''
  endif
  let evar = evar[ 0 : len(evar) - 2 ]

  " glob candidates, remove leading evar+prefix
  let candidates = map(glob(evar . mid . base . '*', 0, 1), {i,v -> v[ len(evar . mid) : ]})
  call complete(col('.') - len(base), candidates)
  return ''
endfunction
```